# Cannot plot in Matlab. It says my matrix is empty. Weird?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Doing some simple plotting and I cannot seem to figure out why I can't plot my data. I troubleshooted it first by checking to see if I had any data in my arrays first. I did not!! I'm completely lost on how to fix this.

[image]

I also tried creating a script to see if maybe it solved the issue instead of using the command window. I still get the same error.

Code:

```
t=0:1e-6:((2e-3-1e-6)-1);
vm=sin(2*pi*1e3*t);
vc=sin(2*pi*20e3*t);
vdsb=vc.*vm;
plot(t,vdsb,'b')
```

Comment: ((2e-3-1e-6)-1) < 0 so t has size of 0 elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't want that last `-1` in your code setting up `t`. Try changing `t` to:

```
t=0:1e-6:((2e-3-1e-6));
```

Or, if you really want it negative, you need to change the step size to negative:

```
t=0:-1e-6:((2e-3-1e-6)-1);
```

Otherwise, t is defined from `0:psotiveStep:negativeNumber` and so it is empty.